# How to make Image button stay in clicked state after being clicked

Tags: javascript

I basically would like to disable the Rollout and rollover function after I clicked. I tried an if argument but I can't get it to work. Sorry I am a real beginner in this.

I already achieved to change a text with the click in mother div but still can't disable other functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<script>

var Enabled = true;    
function down() 
{
document.getElementById("button").src = "images/click.png"; }   


var Enabled = true;
function rollover()
{
if(Enabled == true)
{
document.getElementById("button").src = "images/on.png";
}else
{
document.getElementById("button").src = "images/click.png";
}
} 

var Enabled = true;
function rollout()
{
if(Enabled == true)
{
document.getElementById("button").src = "images/off.png";
}else
{
document.getElementById("button").src = "images/click.png";
}
} 


function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
}

<script/>

<body> 


<h1>My Web Page</h1>


<div class="test1">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><p id="demo">A Paragraph</p></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="images/off.png" id="button" 
onMouseOver="rollover ()" onMouseOut="rollout ()" 
onMouseDown="down()"
onClick="myFunction()"
onClick="this.innerHTML=down()
onMouseUp="rollover ()";/></div>

<div class="col">col3</div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stat by fixing your inline handlers - you can even see where they fail on the color coding. You cannot have two onclicks. Add a semicolon to stack them: `onClick="myFunction(); this.innerHTML=down()"` and remember your quotes. Also mouseDown is triggered onClick

Comment: Idea is to add a class on click or mousedown and then check if the element has that class when these (onMouseOver="rollover ()" onMouseOut="rollout ()" ) are triggered return false if you have that class

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/eqi3tN8QQvhBHIhP2haB?p=preview), When clicked it calls down() which sets Enabledto false and chages the image, now when you rollover and rollout it checks if Enabled is true, if it isn't it wont change the image.

```
function down(ele) 
{
  ele.src = "//placekitten.com/50/30"; //Clicked
  Enabled = false; }
```

Comment: Dear Andreas, I think get the idea but don't know how to call for the function in the HTML. I am also really confused with these enabled false arguments as I couldn't make any of them to work so far:( Thanks for your help anyway:)

Comment: What functions do you have trouble calling?

Comment: well I was toying with the idea to set functions to enable or false through the on click event. But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the hoooooly grail:)

Its a little tricky solution but works:)

I change the div instead of disabling the functions of the button states.

So here it is:

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('button2').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("button").style.display = "none";
}
```

Button2 is now the clicked button state, button is the div where all the other states are in. This way it stays in the clicked state after clicking and I get rid of the other button states after clicking:)